# How to credit a photo taken by someone else in my publication?

Tags: publications, graphics

How do authors normally address a photo courtesy? 
I have a photo taken by Dr. X, I would like to use it in my paper which is planned to be submitted to an engineering journal. How should I respect the photo credit? 
is it okay to write  this in the figure caption, like:

```
\caption{blah blah  .... (photo courtesy of Dr. X).}
```

should I even mention the title Dr?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'd like to use a figure from a paper, what's the best way to do this?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/id-like-to-use-a-figure-from-a-paper-whats-the-best-way-to-do-this)

Comment: @scaaahu I'm not sure that it's a duplicate. The OP doesn't mention that the photo is from a published paper, as is the case in the other question.

Comment: @user3327426 _I have a photo taken by Dr. X_, How did you get that photo?

Comment: @silvado I just asked the OP to clarify. I guess I might have made a bad assumption.

Comment: I removed the copyright tag because I'm assuming that the photo is used with permission of Dr X and there's no actual copyright issue (as the body of the post doesn't say anything about a copyright concern); if that's not the case, there's quite a lot of necessary detail missing from this post.

Comment: its not from a paper. its a raw photo.
And Dr X he himself sent the photo to me, so absolute permission

Comment: @user3327426 That Dr X sent the photo to you may not always mean that you have permission to publish it. You may have that permission, but if not, you should clarify.

Comment: You should get your permission (actually a license) *in writing*. Email is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Credit lines for photographs should be displayed conspicuously with the photo or in a footnote on the same page. In general, it should look something like: "© Ansel Adams 2015" or "© 2015 Ansel Adams". Alternatively, if the photo was given to you for general use, use something like: "photo courtesy of Ansel Adams".

Some guidelines for citing images in various formats are posted here: [University of Cincinnati](http://guides.libraries.uc.edu/content.php?pid=285456&sid=2367919). Near the bottom of that website there is a short section with advice on photo credit lines.