# Proper way of including pictures into the Master's thesis

Tags: citations, thesis, mathematics, masters

I'm doing mathematics and my thesis consists mainly of understanding and elaborating couple of articles, writing clearly everything down, and possibly including a little of my own original work at the end. Of course, I am citing everything, and also I am not copypasting, rather writing known stuff with my own words and trying to be more detailed.

But I am not sure what to do with the pictures(there are about 20 of them which are relatively difficult to draw, next to the 30-35 pages of plain text). I have an access to the tex files of these articles and could easily copy paste the code for pictures. On the other hand, I could write down(rather draw) everything by myself, and anyway I would properly cite the source because many of these pictures represent ideas behind which are not mine.

So what should I do? On the one hand, straight copypasting is not good. On the other hand, this is not a piece of text where I could write more details, although if I wouldn't have seen those pictures but I would been explained the ideas, then I would have drawn slightly differently. Should I draw everything by myself, while trying to be visually different then authors(while properly citing them of course).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'd like to use a figure from a paper; what's the best way to do this?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/id-like-to-use-a-figure-from-a-paper-whats-the-best-way-to-do-this)

Comment: @GoodDeeds That link will be helpful, thanks. But I am not just asking how to cite. I am asking if it is alright to cite 20 of them. Will it be comparable to the case of plainly copypasting 5 pages of text from another course? I know that in my thesis I should more sort of paraphrase and add more details, given a work which is not mine, rather than copypaste.

Comment: _I am asking if it is alright to cite 20 of them_ Please read the answers of the linked question about getting permissions.