# I want to include a figure from a paper I wrote and is now published in a blog article, what's the best way to do this?

Tags: citations, copyright, graphics, online-publication, blog

I was reading this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3100/100532), and I was wondering what differences related to copyright (if any) there might be if I want to include one of the figures from an article I wrote and had published in a journal in a blog article I am writing summarizing my research.

Since the blog will be made public, I assume I will still need to get permission from the journal, but I'm unsure if being on a blog or my own previous work changes anything.

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of the law, or are you more worried about actual practice? Your being the creator of the figure is important in one context, but not the other.

Comment: I'm only interested in not violating copyright laws. I'm not asking about how to cite or get the image.

Comment: I might suggest adding that clarification (i.e. "what differences relating to copyright") to your question for posterity, then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't still hold copyright to the journal article, then you need to get permission to use the figure and you need to cite the original. Your agreement with the publisher or the terms under which the article was published may, already, give you a license to do this. So, no, the requirements aren't different for blogs.